# How to retrieve an attribute of a react element inside a class using selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

This is the HTML. I want to retrieve the value **Unblock** from the element in the  4th line using selenium webdriver in python. Please help me regarding the same.

```
<a class="btn btn-micro hasTooltip" 
    href="javascript:void(0);" 
    onclick="return listItemTask('cb0','users.unblock')" 
    title="" data-original-title="Unblock">
    <span class="icon-unpublish">
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  myText = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-micro.hasTooltip[onclick*='users.unblock']"))).get_attribute("data-original-title")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  myText = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-micro hasTooltip'][contains(@onclick,'users.unblock')]"))).get_attribute("data-original-title")
  ```

Comment: Why do you think that target link is *"React element"*?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
driver.findElement_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-micro hasTooltip']").get_attribute("data-original-title");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print attribute value in an element then you have to use `getAttribute()` method. You can use this code, you can convert it into Python as it is in JAVA

```
WebElement eletext= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-micro hasTooltip']"));

String textElement = eletext.getAttribute("data-original-title");    
System.out.println(textElement);
```

Difference:

**getAttribute()** - It extracts the text of any attribute in the HTML tag.

**getText()** - It extracts the innerText of a WebElement.

Comment: Now, you tell me how does this answer differ from my answer?

Comment: You are writing the same answer as mine, no difference.

Comment: Man he want to print that element your answer dont have that thing. As I dont know Python so I gave answer in JAVA.